# foreach: binding not working ko.mapping.fromJS data

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to display a list (using foreach) of jobs I get from a JSON request (See below) using the ko.mapping.fromJS, but its coming up blank.. The JSON data appears to be properly loaded inthe observables array but doesn't render in the HTML????

This is actually part of mobile web app (Jquery Mobile) so the data appears on the second page, not sure if that makes a difference (I load all the code up at the beginning)

**HTML (simplified)**

```
<ul  data-bind="foreach: JobsToday " >
 <li>   <span data-bind="text: job_id"> </span>   </li>
 </ul>
```

**JSON DATA (simplified)**

```
[{"job_id":"1753","driver_id":"23"},{"job_id":"1754","driver_id":"23"}]
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var JobsToday=ko.observableArray([]);  // observable array holds the jobs  for the current day  

 function DispatchModel(){

    self = this;  //cache the current context
    self.userd_id= 0;

        $.getJSON(controller_php_script+"/",  {'action' : 'list_driver_jobs', 'driver_id' : self.user_id}, function(jobsData) 
        {

     self.JobsModelArray= ko.mapping.fromJS(jobsData); // get the jobs
         JobsToday =self.JobsModelArray;  //assign to global observable

 //print out the observablbles to make sure data is three
      console.log( " JobsModelArray: "+   ko.toJSON( JobsToday ) );  
                });

} //end of DispatchModel


// Start of our  main function 
$(document).ready(function () {

    var vm = new DispatchModel();   //create the Dispatch VMM
    ko.applyBindings(vm);  //knockout.js apply the binding

});  //end $(document).ready

    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `JobsToday` observable array is outside the view model function. Since you bound the form to the `DisplayModel`, it can't be bound to. Move the `JobsToday` inside the function.

```
 function DispatchModel(){

    self = this;  //cache the current context
    self.JobsToday=ko.observableArray([]);  // observable array holds the jobs  for the current day
```

Second problem is that you set `JobsToday` to the data you mapped. This is a common error with beginners in Knockout. You set observables via the function, not directly. It would work better like this:

```
var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(jobsData); // get the jobs
self.JobsToday(mapped);  //assign to observableArray
```

Comment: Yep, you got me on the right track I consolidated a couple of varaibles and found that the command:

ko.mapping.fromJS(jobsData,{},self.JobsToday ); // map the user driver data to this model

did the trick... yeah remembering to assign object with object(assign_me) versus the equals.. was the key, thanks.